# Xrandr displaying "Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, display, gnome, xrandr

My Sys specs :

```
**Intel i7-8700k (Coffe-lake),Mother board : ROG(Maximus X Hero)
OS :Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04**
```

I booted My new PC with **Ubutnu-Gnome16.04** , after installation the screen resolution is **1024x768(4:3)**--and screen is shown "Unknown Display".
I havent installed anything in my new OS.My Monitor-CPU connecting Cable is **DP(Pin Cable).**

I have tried with "Force create new resolution":

```
 a)cvt 1366 768 60
 b)xrandr --newmode "< >"
```

Then Error throws as :

> "xrandr : Failed to get size of gamma for output default".
>   I want perfect resolution to be fit for my desktop screen 
>   Can Anyone help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on info in this article I've found answer.

You need to add `"i915.alpha_support=1"` booting parameter to GRUB (Info from here) :

Log in to the system and start a terminal window (Applications->Accessories->Terminal).

In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Enter your password when prompted by [sudo]. (If the file /etc/default/grub appears to be empty or does not exist, see the instructions for earlier releases above).

In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"` then edit that line, adding your parameter(s) to the text inside the double-quotes after the words `"quiet splash"`. (Be sure to add a SPACE after "splash" before adding your new parameter.)

it should look like this `"quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"`

Click the Save button, then close the editor window.

In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command: `sudo update-grub` Restart the system.

Comment: [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=coffee-uhd-graphics&num=1) there is more information why it works -

Comment: In short, the i915 driver in the kernel version you have does not have full support for the platform. Enabling it by default has a risk of causing black screens. Thus you have to manually enable the alpha level support in the driver. Later kernel versions won't need this, as the driver has been improved to cover the platform properly.

Comment: I am on Debian. I do have the same issue. Unfortunately, this answer didn't helped me. Note:  There were only "quite" instead of "quiet splash".

Answer (score 3):

An answer I found on the askubuntu forum <sup>[1]</sup> solved the problem for me:

Open the following: 
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find the following line, uncomment it and change it to `1920x1080`: 
`#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`  --> `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080`

Update it: 
`sudo update-grub`

Then restart your computer:  
`sudo reboot`

[1] https://askubuntu.com/a/1167437/724074

Comment: Half a great answer! This solved the problem but caused a whole new one, now my monitor struggles to update movements. For example, scrolling down to this part of the screen/page took about 8 seconds (as opposed to 0.5 seconds.)

Comment: finally figured out part two > I switched the Nvidia drivers to the open source one and everything is looking great

Comment: not worked on ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had nvidia drivers issues after changing system default gcc.

I had only one resolution option (800x600) and I've found a hint on the nvidia thread (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-18-10/70495/2).

> You have your system compiler set to clang/llvm but gcc 7.5 is needed.
> Please set your cc back to gcc-7.5 using update-alternatives